# Span text is at the top instead of middle

Tags: css

I have a `<div>` I'm trying to line up so all the text is `vertical-align: middle;`

```
<div 
    class="col-md-6" 
    style="padding-right: 0px; vertical-align: ">
    <select 
        class="DropDownListDark submenu-dropdown" 
        id="SortProperties_SortBy" 
        name="SortProperties.SortBy" onchange="sortList()" 
        style="float: right; vertical-align: middle; ">
        <option value="Title desc">Title (desc)</option>
    </select>
    <span style="float: right; vertical-align: middle; height: 100%; ">Sort by: &nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

However, the text stays at the top of the `<div>`.

When I inspect the `<span>` and look at Computed values I don't see anything that would cause that:

> box-sizing:  border-box
>   display:     block
>   float:       right
>   height:      15px
>   line-height: 15.7143px
>   text-align:  left
>   vertical-align: middle
>   width:       44px

The containing `<div>` has this:

> box-sizing: border-box
>   display: block
>   float: left
>   height: 28px
>   line-height: 15.7143px
>   min-height: 1px
>   padding-left: 15px
>   padding-right: 0px
>   position: relative
>   text-align: left
>   vertical-align: middle
>   width: 495px

Changing both of them to use `display: inline-block;` doesn't fix this either. The text, 'Sort by:' is still aligned at the top of the select control.

How can I fix this?

Comment: please try to refine your code

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: table-cell` on the `div` instead of `display: block`.

Also, you can read up on how to use `vertical-align` here:
http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/

Comment: Didn't help. I've seen tutorials like that before. Something else in the CSS must be messed up. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to set `line-height` of `span` to the same value as is `height` of `div`. So in your case:

> line-height: 28px;